# Adding jBox2D to Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jbox2d

I would like to add `jBox2D` to my Android game, and I've included the .jar file in the Project Structure/Dependencies, but my app keeps crashing at the World object creation.

The error message is

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Maven, just paste .jar file in the project directory.  And include following line in the dependencies section of Gradle build:

```
compile files('jbox2d-library-[version].jar')
```

If you are using Maven refer [Jbox2d getting starter guide](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jbox2d/wikis/QuickStart.wiki#Jar_Releases)

Comment: Gradle pulls the dependencies from Maven repositories, so why use a file?